# image id in canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Image load dynamically:

`imageObj.src = "source";`

Button click code:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
        {
            var value = 0;
            $('#left').click(function ()
            {
                alert("left click");
                value -= 90;
                $('#img').rotate({ animateTo: value });

            });
            $('#right').click(function ()
            {
                value += 90;
                $('#img').rotate({ animateTo: value });
            });
        });
```

I have loaded the image dynamically in canvas button click, but I have to rotate image in canvas clockwide and anticlockwise.

When I take hardcoded img tag in html it works, but my functionality does not work when image loaded dynamically.

Comment: What exactly is your question? You want to get an image id? You want to use your rotate plugin on canvases? You want to draw rotated pictures on canvas?

Comment: I want to get an image id on button click

Comment: You have the id already, it's "img" - isn't it? But you can only select elements by id which are in the DOM tree - your Image object from loadCanvas is not.

Comment: But i have loaded image dynamically in canvas. So how i rotate image when it is in canvas.

Comment: No, you have not loaded it "into canvas", like a DOM subnode - you've drawn the picture on the canvas. It's only pixels now.

Comment: so it is impossible to get image id :(

Comment: @John, you don't seem to understand what DOM is. As Bergi explained, you must have created in the DOM document a canvas element. This canvas element is a node in the DOM structure and can have ID attribute assigned (doesn't have to), your image is drawn into this canvas element and DOM doesn't know about it. If you need to rotate the image on click, keep reference in the memory to that image. Looking at the rotate plugin, you want to create IMG tag instead.

Comment: so it is impossible to get image id i am right i know dom very well but dnt have idea abt canvas now i clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like Bergi mentioned you are rotating virtually, nothing drawn to canvas.
Here is a working example i prepared for you :

http://jsfiddle.net/gurkavcu/J9B3k/

You can rotate image object like this :

```
 $('#left').click(function() {

        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.translate((imageObj.width / 2), (imageObj.height /2));
        context.rotate(-90 * Math.PI / 180);
        context.translate(-(imageObj.width / 2), -(imageObj.height / 2));
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, imageObj.width , imageObj.height);


    });
    $('#right').click(function() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.translate((imageObj.width / 2 ), (imageObj.height / 2));
        context.rotate(90 * Math.PI / 180);
        context.translate(-(imageObj.width / 2), -(imageObj.height / 2));
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, imageObj.width , imageObj.height);
    });
```

Comment: js fiddle not loading an image